# Register onclick for animated ImageView

Tags: android, onclick, android-animation

I've got an ImageView I animated using a translate animation to infinitely drop my image down the screen.  I want to register touches that are made to the ImageView as it falls however my onClick handler is never called unless I click in the ImageView original location.

Is there someway to identify when the animated image was clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A translate animation is a view animation that is only going to change where the view is visually drawn, not the actual position. You either need to switch to using one of the property animations, or write a custom view animation that specifically updates the view's position with setX or setY.

Example code for that:

```
public void doCustomAnimation(){
    final Float startingPoint= mLittleChef.getX();
    Animation animation = new Animation()
       {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                mLittleChef.setX(startingPoint - (int)(startingPoint/2 * interpolatedTime));
        }

        };
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        simpleLock= false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    });
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animation.setRepeatCount(1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    animation.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration/2);
    mLittleChef.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

You can read more about view animations here: [HERE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/2d-animation-for-android-series-comparing-and-contrasting-different-ways-of-doing-the-same-part-II)

And if you want to use property animations: [HERE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/2d-animation-for-android-series-comparing-and-contrasting-different-ways-of-doing-the-same)

Comment: Thank u Whitney. I used an objectAnimator and it worked great :-)

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you aren't really updating the position after the animation.

To achieve that, just call setFillEnabled every time you execute the animation:

```
animation.setFillEnabled(true);
```